# SignalR not working in website but works in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, signalr

I followed this simple [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-1x/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) and managed to create a test web application with signalR. But when I tried to recreate it using ASP.NET website and then browse for the html page, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: $.connection is undefined
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
```

This is the structure of my project if this matters:

[image]

Based on what I found, setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true in web.config is necessary, so I already did it. Also the tutorial I followed is a little bit outdated since I use VS 2010(i.e. .NET Framework 4) which is only compatible with SignalR v 1.1.3.

How come I can't get this working in a website but works perfectly in a web application?

**Update:**

One **solution**(which I believe to be right) suggests to

> Put my code behind file in a seperate .cs file and put that cs file in
>   App_Code folder

So I tried to change my html file into a .aspx file. This way I have a code behind file (i.e. .aspx.cs) But I'm confused on what it is meant to move the code behind file because nesting my .aspx file to a .aspx.cs file residing in App_Code folder is not allowed.

What does that quoted answer above means?

**Update:**

Here are my script references in HTMLPage.htm together with the main function.

```
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message. 
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.  
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @LarsHöppner What do you mean by adding the html page?

Comment: @LarsHöppner I think this problem is already solved [here - the second answer by ozgkrc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457910/object-undefined-error-at-var-chat-connection-chat-while-using-signalr?lq=1). But it seems that I have only little idea on what exactly he says. Can you please shed light on this?

Comment: I don't think that answer applies here - in your case, $.connection isn't defined, which means the SignalR script isn't initializing at all. That's why I asked for the HTML of the page you're visiting - to see whether the respective js files are included.

Comment: @LarsHöppner I have included the code that might help.

Comment: Make sure there are no other jQuery references - also see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20352832/2001735)

Comment: @LarsHöppner I still can't fix this thing. Please see the real file [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=18441964393119245701)(an asp.net website). Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always check the console when something doesn't work - in your case, the page simply can't find the references to the SignalR script and to /signalr/hubs (and it says so in the console). If you change the urls to "/WebSite18/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js" and "/Website18/signalr/hubs", it will work.

Comment: Holy cow it worked but I don't get it why. This is the first time that someone suggested me to include the project/website name in the directory of referencing js files. Having just doing drag-and-drop to automate the work of referencing them and let VS to do it for me, and this is just the case of putting me in trouble. I also looked and followed the tutorials, met some with similar problems and this is the only problem? This is madness for me. But how do this work exactly Lars?

Comment: It's because of the document root of your web server / the virtual path of the website project. Instead of changing the src paths, you can also right-click your website project in the solution explorer, click "Properties Window" and change the virtual path to "/".

Comment: Oh that's it - because of my virtual path! But why did referencing JQuery like `src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"` or the old normal way still works and the other two does not?

Comment: You're using google's CDN in your example, this is not relative to your server.

Comment: Hmm yes that's what I uploaded. But as of now, I am using JQuery 1.6.4 bundled with signalR 1.1.3 and looks like `src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"` without the /WebSite18. I wonder why is this so? Or maybe this is signalR specific. Or maybe I'm wrong? But either way, very much thanks for your help.

Comment: It simply means there's a file at that location in your file system, so you can check in explorer. Also: try right-clicking and opening the script in a new tab, this will show the full path it is using. If you omit the leading /, it will load relative to the current location, so if you're already in /WebSite18/, it will work. With the / at the start, it will look at the document root.

Comment: The reason why I asked this is to fix signalR issue while using the LiveChat Starter Kit (LCSK) from codeplex. And I have the same issue as above. Now it works great. Thanks.